# How to make terminal read only?

Tags: terminal, readonly

How can I make a terminal read only?

Example scenario to give some background-context:

**I know one time before (was quite awhile ago) - in Kali-Linux you could make a terminal read-only, but I cannot do that any more in Kali, or in any other Linux-based Operating System**

I have some clues to what a solution *could* be, (maybe) it is..

- a package? That I just need to reinstall / or install ?
- a configuration? (Maybe a file somewhere, or a command I need to run to enable/config it)
- some OS-Specific thingy(ies)

If you make it read only, it will not be possible to click it,  or press enter, or enter anything - until you disable it.

Why? It could be really convenient in situations where you need to have a terminal open (to load, or have something running) but it's critical to not touch it, or accidentally, like  type in it

Comment: what, exactly, do you mean by "make a terminal read-only"?

Comment: well,  if you make it read only, it will not be possible to click it,  or press enter, or enter anything,

Comment: So you want to disable terminal input?

Comment: Yeah I guess so,  it was a button before, "Make terminal read-only" but yes, if  possible, I would really like to prefer to  not-being able to close it either, until disabled (IF possible) 

shortly, yes. & Thx for  helping me out!

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?  The "read-only-terminal" is not your problem, but a possible solution you have in mind, right?  Ask about the problem you want to solve.  You will get better answers.

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! I rolled back your recent edit tagging the title with "SOLVED".  Accepting an answer will mark the question as resolved. Please see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @Kusalananda  Oh  okay, thanks  I didn't see that small detail,  anyway, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gnome-terminal` has this option. I assume some distros just changed their default desktop environment. `gnome-terminal` should not be depending on too many gnome-libraries, so the installation would not take much space.